# How can I start a shutdown with cron,only if no download is in progress?

Tags: bash, cron

I would like to shutdown my computer half-past twelve every day and can do that with "echo "30 0 * * * /sbin/shutdown -h now" > myrootcron.sh",but what if I want to cancel that shutdown or leave it out because I have a download in progress ?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what all your `echo` stuff is about but if you just want to check if a particular process is running, you can use `pgrep` on your schedule. This will return `0` if if finds a process that matches.

I'm assuming you're downloading with `wget` but you can just change that to whatever process you'd expect to see alive (use `htop` to inspect the system while downloading if you aren't sure.)

```
30 0 * * *    pgrep wget >/dev/null || shutdown -h now
```

If (as above) you're only running this once a day, and it doesn't trigger due to a download, it won't shutdown until the next day. You could alter this to run it hourly between 00:30 and 07:30:

```
30 0-7 * * *    pgrep wget >/dev/null || shutdown -h now
```

Comment: Please clarify me, the command means if pgrep has a exit status of 0 then shutdown the system. Doesn't it be if the exit status is not 0 then shutdown i.e. `pgrep wget >/dev/null || shutdown -h now` ?

Comment: @heemayl yes. I'm sure that's what Oli meant. I have edited to make it clear.

Comment: Yes. +1 for the good answer.